# How to setup Azure Active Directory to support Single Sign On

Tags: azure, directory, single-sign-on

I want to know how to setup Microsoft Azure Active Directory (AAD) to support login with email & password on mobile app. The email could be any email (google, apple, custom domain, etc) and I will generate the 4 digits password for each user.

But when using AAD, I can only add microsoft account, and when I try to add 3rd email (via csv file), AAD generate another microsoft email base on the custom domain I've added and the 3rd email is consider as external email. 
=> Can I use 3rd email to login?
=> Since the password for each user is generate by AAD, So I want to pre-set password with my own 4 digits number. Can I do that? Does AAD provide any method that I can change all password for users

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c).  It supports SSO scenarios where users sign in with their non-microsoft social media accounts, or create custom logins.

The [Set-MsolUserPassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194140.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet can be used to set user passwords, but this will not work for Microsoft and social media accounts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've tried Azure B2c and success login via their mobile example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios
But on the mobile app, I cannot automatically login, app open a login web page which user have to key-in their username & password. How could I do the auto login?

Comment: There is documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-overview/) describing how to set it up for IOS. So evidently it should be supported.

Comment: I tried it out from a consumer perspective by adding a well known company app to my Azure AD SSO configuration.  Presumably they use Azure B2C, which is why it showed up in Azure as an available SSO app.  I joined my Surface to the Azure AD Domain, signed into Windows 10 with my Azure credentials, opened Chrome, and navigated to the special link Azure provided for the company app.  Chrome asked me for my login again, so I switched to IE.  IE prompted install of a plugin, but after that, I no longer had to use passwords to access that companies site.  How cool is that ?!

Comment: Oh, one other note.  The Google Play Store has a Microsoft App that is installed for authentication purposes.  Something like this may be necessary for Azure B2C to work properly.